# Backup web приложения

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, резервное-копирование, lamp

Существует Linux сервер, на котором крутится Apache, PHP, MySQL, GitLab, Shiny. На этот сервер по ssh постоянно ходят разработчики и используют его как песочницу (начиная от расчетных скриптов, заканчивая frontend-ом). Текущий backup делается скриптом на bash и упаковывается в tgz. Проблемы:

1. Потребность постоянно держать актуальным список файлов для backup-а;
2. Развертывание приложения из backup-а не будет быстрым (больше часа уже критично);
3. Как следствие из предыдущего пункта, плохая переносимость.

Ищу решения, нравится идея запаковать все в Docker контейнер. Взять официальный базовый image Ubuntu и настроить внутри него ssh, LAMP, и т.д. А backup-ы делать docker commit и docker push по cron-у. В качестве версии указывать текущую дату и время. Смущает то, что могут быть подводные камни использования docker-а, которые сложно предугадать. (Например, недавно разворачивал WordPress в Docker-е, оказалось что «WordPress saves the last IP as its ‘Home’ and ‘Site’ URL.». В итоге на другой машине с другим ip wordpress пытался загрузить css/js с ip старого host-а).

Чем плох или хорош такой сценарий использования Docker-а? Какие существуют альтернативные решения для backup-а?

Comment: Предлагаю решение: https://github.com/deatwisedog/ignite-lx/ Делает бэкап системы и кладёт его на NFS. В любой момент можно загрузиться с iso, который он создает и восстановить систему _Целиком_. p.s.Через несколько дней доделаю создание бэкапа на usb-флешке.

Comment: Если бекапить само  приложение , как написано в название темы , то и `GIT` чудесно работает .

Comment: @redroid a база данных?

Comment: ну если есть прод , то база всегда там , можно быстро развернуть с нее , а так mysqdump по крону , бежим по дереву разраб площадок , они наверное как то так `petrov.project.ru` где `petrov` это логин и пароль к базе (для dev то зачем сложности) , сохраняем в одноименный каталог  `/petrov.dump` ну и все , если кому надо он дергает ту базу какая ему нужна или свою. развернуть `mysql` дамп 1 сточка .

Comment: Есть `rsnapshot`, но я не тестил его в боевых условиях.

Comment: ЕМНИП вы не можете бесконечно делать commit и ограничены 127 слоями, часть из которых уже использована базовым изображением.

Comment: @Etki очень ценное замечание

Comment: не лучше-ли использовать rsync, rsnapshot или даже выделить под этот зоопарк отдельную файловую систему и делать бекапы по dump/restore, а не пытаться натянуть это на докер, который для этого не подходит чуть более, чем совсем?

Comment: @ilyapt
Скорее всего теперь сделаю так:
Разбить приложение на несколько контейнеров. Один контейнер -  один процесс (Apache, Shiny, GitLab и т.д.). Разворачивать через docker-compose. Отделить окружение от самого приложения и скармливать стеку из Apache+Shiny+GitLab+... директорию с сорцами. Сорцы бэкапить через rsync и делать dump базы данных. В таком случае окружение станет легко переносимым.

Comment: @Сергей так гораздо лучше